# What is the best way to run a function every 5 minutes in python synced with system clock?

Tags: python, time, delay, clock, modulo

I want to run a function every 5 minutes and have it synced with the clock.  If I use time.sleep(60*5), the time starts to drift because my function adds a tiny bit of processing time.  Is this a good way of running my function synced with the clock or is there a better way in python?

```
def run(condition):

    def task():
        #run data here
        pass

    runOnce = True

    while condition:
        if dt.datetime.now().minute % 5 == 0 and dt.datetime.now().second == 0 and runOnce:
            runOnce = False
            task()

        elif dt.datetime.now().second != 0 and not runOnce:
            runOnce = True

        else:
            time.sleep(0.5)




run(True)
```

Comment: If you are on Mac/Linux, use `cron`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/triggers/interval.html#module-apscheduler.triggers.interval). It uses python's `datetime` module to control the execution thus should be largely independent of your code's peculiarities.

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import BlockingScheduler

@sched.scheduled_job('interval', id='my_job_id', minutes=5)
def job_function():
    print("Hello World")
```

Python also has an inbuilt [scheduler](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sched.html), python's `sched` module with a bit simpler api that should perform in the same way and save you some hassle from maintaining an extra dependency.