# creating a scheduler for specific hours on python

Tags: python, slice

Hi I am attempting to create a method that returns a list containing hours that a program should send an alert, the first alert needs to be sent at 00:00 for all the cases, so it works fine if If create the method using 120 min meaning every two hours, But it does not work to send alerts every 4hours (240 min),

this is my code

```
def candle_close_timings(candle):
    frame = None
    if candle >= 60: frame = candle/60
    print (frame)
    minutes = []
    hours = []
    for hours in range(0, 24):
        minute = 0
        while minute <= 59:
            minutes.append('%02d:%02d' % (hours, minute))
            minute = minute + candle
    del minutes[frame-1::frame]
    return minutes
print (candle_close_timings(120))
```

this works fine, but now please try :

```
print (candle_close_timings(240))
```

it should return

```
[00:00 , 04:00, 08:00...]
```

could anyone give me a hand on how to slice the list

Comment: This is a very cumbersome method of implementing this. Is your method supposed to work with minutes that are not exact multiples of an hour? (i.e. should `candle_close_timings(110)` work?)

Comment: well the client requested the time to be typed in minutes, so i need to convert minutes to hours, the clients also specified that the times need to be 2 and 4 hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating the problem. Here is a much simpler solution given that the method should only work for exact hours (i.e. multiples of `60`):

```
def candle_close_timings(candle):
    return ["{:02}:00".format(hour) for hour in range(0, 24, candle//60)]
```

then

```
print (candle_close_timings(120))
```

result

```
['00:00', '02:00', '04:00', '06:00', '08:00', '10:00', '12:00', '14:00', '16:00', '18:00', '20:00', '22:00']
```

or

```
print (candle_close_timings(240))
```

result

```
['00:00', '04:00', '08:00', '12:00', '16:00', '20:00']
```

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters have indicated, your solution is overly complicated (you run a while loop inside a for loop).

I propose to use the following solution instead. The logic behind it is that one day has exactly 1440 minutes, thus you can easily get the event time in minutes just by looping through `candle*n` numbers.

Then we can convert the minutes into time using two simple division operations: a quotient will give you hours `minutes / 60` while the remainder `minutes % 60` will give you the remaining minutes.

Therefore

`print (candle_close_timings(120))`

will give you

`['00:00', '02:00', '04:00', '06:00', '08:00', '10:00', '12:00', '14:00', '16:00', '18:00', '20:00', '22:00']`

and

`print (candle_close_timings(110))`

will return

`['00:00', '01:50', '03:40', '05:30', '07:20', '09:10', '11:00', '12:50', '14:40', '16:30', '18:20', '20:10', '22:00', '23:50']`

Full solution is thus:

```
import math
def candle_close_timings(candle):
    #one day has 1440 minutes
    schedule = ['00:00']
    # we use ceil here to make sure to add one last event if the event time does not perfectly fit into the day (1440 % candle != 0)
    for event in range(1, int(math.ceil(1440/candle))):
        # every event advances a preceeding even by candle minutes
        time_step = candle * event
        # we then get the hour of the event by dividing the minutes by 60 and taking the result
        hrs = int(time_step / 60)
        # we then get the hour of the event by dividing the minutes by 60 and taking the remainder
        mins = int(time_step % 60)
        # format the string into a hourly string
        schedule.append('%02d:%02d' % (hrs, mins))
    return schedule
print (candle_close_timings(120))
```

Comment: this is a wonderful answer for my whole problem, I think is a much more optimized solution to the my problem, because your solution includes answers to problems that will come later, when my client wants to set alerts every 3 minutes for instance. I really appreciate, I cant give you the check because your answer came second, but you get a point for sure.

Comment: If you are planning to run this code in a production environment, check out my other answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061828/what-is-the-best-way-to-run-a-function-every-5-minutes-in-python-synced-with-sys/59061990#59061990 You can achieve the same result with dedicated python tools in an argueable more efficient and less boilerplate-y way.

Comment: thank you very much, seems to be a very interesting scheduler, I am too far into the development face of this project, but for other projects I will have it into account.